# Javax timer issues

Tags: java, timer

I have an AbstractShape class that draws a shape to the panel (this class is abstract and there are "Rect" and "Oval" classes that extends it).
I'm trying to use javax timer in order to make the shape flash (by filling and drawing it again empty every 2 seconds).
When I run the function, the shape changes its "fill" only when I'm resizing the screen, and I don't understand why :(

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public abstract class AbstractShape extends JPanel implements Shape{

private int x;
private int y;
private int width;
private int height;
private boolean isFilled;
private Color color;

public AbstractShape(int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean isFilled, Color color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.isFilled = isFilled;
    this.color = color;
}

@Override
public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

@Override
public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

@Override
public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
}

@Override
public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}

@Override
public boolean isFilled() {
    return isFilled;
}

public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
    isFilled = filled;
}

@Override
public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}

@Override
public boolean equals (Object O){
    if (O instanceof AbstractShape){
        if (this.getWidth() == ((AbstractShape) O).getWidth() && this.getHeight() == ((AbstractShape) O).getHeight()){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void changeFill(){
    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (isFilled() == true){
                isFilled = false;
                repaint();
            }else{
                isFilled = true;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(2000,listener);
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);
    while(true){
        timer.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

}

public void draw(JPanel panel){
    panel.add(this);
    panel.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

This is the "AbstractShape" class, the "changeFill" function inside needs to make the shape to flash.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(this.getColor());
    if (this.isFilled()){
        g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
    }
    else{
        g.drawRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
    }
}
```

This the "Rect" paintComponent function, that draws the rectangle.

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    // TODO: MAGIC NUMBERS!!!!
    GuiManagement g = new GuiManagement();
    JFrame frame = g.createScreen();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(0,0,700,1000);
    frame.add(panel);
    Rect r = new Rect(20,20,300,300,false,Color.BLUE);
    r.draw(panel);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    r.changeFill();
}
```

And that's the main function that creates a frame, panel, rectangle and calling the ChangeFill function.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: please show the hole code... it's hard to help you with that snippet

Comment: You only need to call `timer.start();` once.

Comment: I added the whole code :)

Comment: @O.O.Balance that's true, I just tried the loop in order to see if it solves the problem. It didn't..

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?